# Why does QGIS Profile plugin lack profile graph?

Tags: qgis, profile

I've searched but can't seem to find a similar issue with this plugin - the plugin starts ok and seems to run but I don't get any view of the profile or some other buttons in the UI as I've seen elsewhere - please see image. I do get the the table of heights which I can export into Excel for graphing but I want to see the profile in QGIS.
I'm running Dufour on a Windows 8 machine and all install using OSGeo4W.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The plotting library used to generate the graph is matplotlib. Check your OSGeo4W advanced install section "libs" if matplotlib is installed.

Comment: It is Anita, that's what's so strange!  It was your blog that first got me onto this and as you can see, I don't get the home, forward/back icons either - I've reinstalled but still no joy!

Comment: I'll try to get my hands on a Win8 system to test.

Comment: Weirdly enough everything looks ok on my Win8 64bit test system. Which options do you see in the plugin settings tab?

Comment: I think it is a problem with the matplotlib library - there is nothing in the settings drop-down so it is not picking it up, also, I seem to have this issues on my works laptop too, which is a Win7 machine!

Comment: Strangely, I have just tried this on the 2.1.0 Dev QGIS and it works!  I see in the settings that matplotlib and Qwt5 are in the drop-down and I can select either option, I am really confused!

Comment: Did you ever resolve this as I've the same problem - the plot library has no drop down despite matplotlib, etc being installed. I'm using the current QGIS 2.9